# How to retrieve data from the url in Vue using window.location.href

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have data that I would like to pass to another page.

Using `this.$router.push({ name: 'toAnotherPage', params: { info: this.info}})` works very well just that it is not refreshing the new page since I'm using SPA. If I can have it refresh the new page I would be fine.

Using `window.location.href = '/toAnotherPage?info=' + this.info` redirects to the new page with the `info` but having challenge retrieving it.

I have tried to use `this.$route.query.info` but not working.

I need help. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by not refreshing? Is the component not getting updated by new data based on param `info`?

Comment: The component is updated but the design is still carrying the old previous page's template. @VamsiKrishna

Comment: can you show the routes? To be exact from which route you are in to which route you want to navigate to with the params

Comment: I am on `if (document.getElementById('guest')) {
    const guest = new Vue({
        el: '#guest',
        components: {
            Guest
        },
        router
    });
}`

trying to go to 

`if (document.getElementById('dashboard')) {
    const dashboard = new Vue({
        el: '#dashboard',
        components: {
            Dashboard
        },
        router
    });
}`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna the new route is in my Laravel web routes